# How to run Javascript code on Mongo Server in PHP?

Tags: php, mongodb

I have written a javascript code to run on the Mongo server (for some more elaborate editing purposes). It runs well oh the mongo shell, the question is how do I run it on PHP?

I am using Mongo 3.2 and php.net says the `execute()` function of the PHP driver is being deprecated. I can't seem to find any recent information on the subject.

Answer (score 1):

execute is just a wrapper over mongo `eval` command which is depreceated since 3.0+, there were many issues with eval due to which it is depreceated.

1. Compatibility: eval was developed before the introduction of sharding. The eval command does not work on sharded clusters at all.
2. Performance: Takes a global lock by default. If eval is with the noLock option, it implies that the javascript could just as easily be run from a client program.
3. Security: You must have access to all actions on all resources in order to run eval. Security best practices depend on being able to segment privileges to actions, and eval gives too broad a range of powers.
4. Maintenance: The server must move to a model where javascript is executed "out of process" for a number of reasons; maintaining support for eval makes this very difficult.

I dont think so that you will be able to exeute this javascript code through PHP driver as of now with mongo 3.2+

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-17453

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `$m` holds your mongo client object:

```
        $eval    = '
db.getCollection("myCollectionName").insertMany([
    {
        "key" : "I_am_a_key",
        "updatedAt" : ISODate("2017-03-24T04:13:57.000Z")
    },
    {
        "doc2" : "haha"
    }
]);
';
        $results = $m->command(['eval' => $eval]);
        foreach ($results as $result) {
            echo PHP_EOL;
            print_r($result);
            // outputs part 1
        }

        $eval    = '
db.getCollection("myCollectionName").insert([
    {
        "simple" : "yes"
    }
]);
';
        $results = $m->command(['eval' => $eval]);
        foreach ($results as $result) {
            echo PHP_EOL;
            print_r($result);
            // outputs part 2
        }
```

1. Make sure your mongodb instance has proper privileges to run `eval` command. By the way `eval` command is deprecated.
2. Accessing $output (for example dumping) *might* cause a segmentation fault error. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/server-side-javascript/ seggusts it has something to do with SELinux (it did not help me though):

> NOTE If you are using SELinux, any MongoDB operation that requires
>   server-side JavaScript will result in segfault errors. Disable
>   Server-Side Execution of JavaScript describes how to disable execution
>   of server-side JavaScript.

3. $output will be of type `MongoDB\Driver\Cursor` and the structure of this Traversable object is is extremely different when calling `insert`, `inserMany` or etc. Output of the provided script:

   ```
   /*
   // output part 1
   Array
   (
       [retval] => Array
           (
               [acknowledged] => 1
               [insertedIds] => Array
                   (
                       [0] => MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID Object
                           (
                               [oid] => 592632451469665d3df5a760
                           )

                       [1] => MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID Object
                           (
                               [oid] => 592632451469665d3df5a761
                           )

                   )

           )

       [ok] => 1
   )
   // output part 2
   Array
   (
       [retval] => Array
           (
               [nInserted] => 1
               [nUpserted] => 0
               [nMatched] => 0
               [nModified] => 0
               [nRemoved] => 0
               [getUpsertedIds] => MongoDB\BSON\Javascript Object
                   (
                       [code] => function () {
               return bulkResult.upserted;
           }
                       [scope] =>
                   )

               [getUpsertedIdAt] => MongoDB\BSON\Javascript Object
                   (
                       [code] => function (index) {
               return bulkResult.upserted[index];
           }
                       [scope] =>
                   )

               [getRawResponse] => MongoDB\BSON\Javascript Object
                   (
                       [code] => function () {
               return bulkResult;
           }
                       [scope] =>
                   )

               [hasWriteErrors] => MongoDB\BSON\Javascript Object
                   (
                       [code] => function () {
               return bulkResult.writeErrors.length > 0;
           }
                       [scope] =>
                   )

               [getWriteErrorCount] => MongoDB\BSON\Javascript Object
                   (
                       [code] => function () {
               return bulkResult.writeErrors.length;
           }
                       [scope] =>
                   )

               [getWriteErrorAt] => MongoDB\BSON\Javascript Object
                   (
                       [code] => function (index) {
               if (index < bulkResult.writeErrors.length) {
                   return bulkResult.writeErrors[index];
               }
               return null;
           }
                       [scope] =>
                   )

               [getWriteErrors] => MongoDB\BSON\Javascript Object
                   (
                       [code] => function () {
               return bulkResult.writeErrors;
           }
                       [scope] =>
                   )

               [hasWriteConcernError] => MongoDB\BSON\Javascript Object
                   (
                       [code] => function () {
               return bulkResult.writeConcernErrors.length > 0;
           }
                       [scope] =>
                   )

               [getWriteConcernError] => MongoDB\BSON\Javascript Object
                   (
                       [code] => function () {
               if (bulkResult.writeConcernErrors.length == 0) {
                   return null;
               } else if (bulkResult.writeConcernErrors.length == 1) {
                   // Return the error
                   return bulkResult.writeConcernErrors[0];
               } else {
                   // Combine the errors
                   var errmsg = "";
                   for (var i = 0; i < bulkResult.writeConcernErrors.length; i++) {
                       var err = bulkResult.writeConcernErrors[i];
                       errmsg = errmsg + err.errmsg;
                       // TODO: Something better
                       if (i != bulkResult.writeConcernErrors.length - 1) {
                           errmsg = errmsg + " and ";
                       }
                   }

                   return new WriteConcernError({errmsg: errmsg, code: WRITE_CONCERN_FAILED});
               }
           }
                       [scope] =>
                   )

               [tojson] => MongoDB\BSON\Javascript Object
                   (
                       [code] => function (indent, nolint) {
               return tojson(bulkResult, indent, nolint);
           }
                       [scope] =>
                   )

               [toString] => MongoDB\BSON\Javascript Object
                   (
                       [code] => function () {
               // Suppress all output for the write concern w:0, since the client doesn't care.
               if (writeConcern && writeConcern.w == 0) {
                   return "BulkWriteResult(" + tojson({}) + ")";
               }
               return "BulkWriteResult(" + this.tojson() + ")";
           }
                       [scope] =>
                   )

               [shellPrint] => MongoDB\BSON\Javascript Object
                   (
                       [code] => function () {
               return this.toString();
           }
                       [scope] =>
                   )

               [hasErrors] => MongoDB\BSON\Javascript Object
                   (
                       [code] => function () {
               return this.hasWriteErrors() || this.hasWriteConcernError();
           }
                       [scope] =>
                   )

               [toError] => MongoDB\BSON\Javascript Object
                   (
                       [code] => function () {
               if (this.hasErrors()) {
                   // Create a combined error message
                   var message = "";
                   var numWriteErrors = this.getWriteErrorCount();
                   if (numWriteErrors == 1) {
                       message += "write error at item " + this.getWriteErrors()[0].index;
                   } else if (numWriteErrors > 1) {
                       message += numWriteErrors + " write errors";
                   }

                   var hasWCError = this.hasWriteConcernError();
                   if (numWriteErrors > 0 && hasWCError) {
                       message += " and ";
                   }

                   if (hasWCError) {
                       message += "problem enforcing write concern";
                   }
                   message += " in bulk operation";

                   return new BulkWriteError(bulkResult, singleBatchType, writeConcern, message);
               } else {
                   throw Error("batch was successful, cannot create BulkWriteError");
               }
           }
                       [scope] =>
                   )

               [toSingleResult] => MongoDB\BSON\Javascript Object
                   (
                       [code] => function () {
               if (singleBatchType == null)
                   throw Error("Cannot output single WriteResult from multiple batch result");
               return new WriteResult(bulkResult, singleBatchType, writeConcern);
           }
                       [scope] =>
                   )

           )

       [ok] => 1
   )
   ```